# Google Chrome has stop animating SVGs when used in xhref

Tags: html, google-chrome, svg

Recently I noticed that some animated SVGs that we use, lost their animation when used from inside an SVG Sprite.

We have a file with a couple SVGs that we use in our page, and we usually use them like the following:

```html
<svg width="0" height="0" style="display: none">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="ic_loading_button">
        <path d="M12,1A11,11,0,1,0,23,12,11,11,0,0,0,12,1Zm0,19a8,8,0,1,1,8-8A8,8,0,0,1,12,20Z" opacity=".25"></path>
        <path d="M10.14,1.16a11,11,0,0,0-9,8.92A1.59,1.59,0,0,0,2.46,12,1.52,1.52,0,0,0,4.11,10.7a8,8,0,0,1,6.66-6.61A1.42,1.42,0,0,0,12,2.69h0A1.57,1.57,0,0,0,10.14,1.16Z">
            <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" dur="0.75s" values="0 12 12;360 12 12" repeatCount="indefinite"></animateTransform>
        </path>
    </svg>
</svg>

<div style="display:flex">
    <svg style="width: 8rem;">
        <use href="#ic_loading_button"></use>
    </svg>

    <svg style="width: 8rem;" viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="ic_loading_button">
        <path d="M12,1A11,11,0,1,0,23,12,11,11,0,0,0,12,1Zm0,19a8,8,0,1,1,8-8A8,8,0,0,1,12,20Z" opacity=".25"></path>
        <path d="M10.14,1.16a11,11,0,0,0-9,8.92A1.59,1.59,0,0,0,2.46,12,1.52,1.52,0,0,0,4.11,10.7a8,8,0,0,1,6.66-6.61A1.42,1.42,0,0,0,12,2.69h0A1.57,1.57,0,0,0,10.14,1.16Z">
            <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" dur="0.75s" values="0 12 12;360 12 12" repeatCount="indefinite"></animateTransform>
        </path>
    </svg>
</div>
```

This worked until a couple weeks ago and we got a spinning SVG for a loading overlay.
It still works in Firefox and other browsers, but not in Chrome or Edge.

If we use the SVG directly without loading it from the `xlink:href`, it works correctly.

Anyone knows why this happened in Chrome recently or how it can be solved?

Thank you in advance.

### Update

As mentioned by @enxaneta, removing the style="display: none" makes the SVG animate in Chrome. However, we will need to support Internet Explorer and if I remove the `display: none`, all the icons show on top of each other on the beginning of the page.

Any sugestion?

Comment: Remove `style="display: none"`

Comment: How does that magic make it work?!? We have a file with plenty SVGs on the beginning of the page, wouldn't that make the pages less usable?

Comment: @enxaneta if I remove that, it works, however, we have that since we still have to support old IE users (I know, I'm sad too, but they pay the bills). If I remove it, in IE, all the icons show on top of the page...

Comment: Solving nothing more, please note that `xlink:href` is now [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href).

Comment: @Philippe thanks for the feedback, according to the docs I can change the `xlink:href` to only `href` and I'll do so. But the problem still happens in chrome. I'll update my answer, thanks!

Comment: you can also use `position: absolute;` and `left:` a very big value. This will hide the svg outside the window.

Comment: You're welcome. I also noticed that the two objects have the same ID, that is not CSS rules compliant. I suspect you're working on a site written by someone else. Maybe somewhere in the code, the developer displays either the first or the second occurrence of the svg, depending on the browser, playing with their display property.

Comment: @RobertLongson Ding ding ding! That `visibility="hidden"` works! Do you see any disadvantage in using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

display="none" is best avoided as much as possible with SVG if you actually intend to display that content for something e.g. via a `<use>` element, as the contents of a filter or pattern etc. The SVG specification would suggest that this ought to work but in reality it does rather conflict with how browsers actually (have to) implement display="none"

You should be able to use visibility="hidden" instead in most cases.